# Is $\frac{d}{dx}$ the same as $\frac{d(1)}{dx}$?

Tags: differential-operators

I have a quantum mechanics problem asking me to prove that the commutator of $x$ and $p$ is equal to some value. In my computation I get something along the lines of

$$
(a*x) \frac{d}{dx} - (b)\frac{d(x)}{dx}
$$

Is this expression equivalent to the expression

$$
(a*x) \frac{d(\textbf{1})}{dx} - (b)\frac{d(x)}{dx}
$$
Where $\textbf{1}$ is the one function, not the number one.

Comment: So, if $f(x) = (a∗x)\frac{d}{dx}−(b)\frac{d(x)}{dx}$ then $f(x)$ would itself be an operator?

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{d}{dx}:C^1 \to C$ is an operator, while $\frac{d1}{dx}$ is a function of $x$.

Here $C^1$ denotes the space of first order differentiable functions, and $C$ denotes continuous functions.

Answer (score 2):

Though this isn't what you asked, what you actually want to do is write

$$(x \circ \frac{d}{dx}-\frac{d}{dx} \circ x)f=x\frac{df}{dx}-\frac{d(xf)}{dx}$$

and then simplify the result. You should find that it is just $-f$. Thus $x \circ \frac{d}{dx}-\frac{d}{dx} \circ x$ corresponds to multiplication by $-1$.

The point here is that $x \circ \frac{d}{dx}-\frac{d}{dx} \circ x$ is not a number, it is an operator, so it only does something when applied to an appropriate function.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies my confusion on the issue. I assumed, to get rid of my extraneous derivative, there had to be an implied function on which it was operating (i.e. the "one function"). I simply did not provide the anonymous function necessary to complete the problem. Thanks.